# Processing dynamic radio buttons in PHP POST

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3, and am generating a dynamic list of radio button groups.

So there are a various number of courses in the db, and I want to display them in a list with an assign yes/no button.

Dynamically generated radio group below:

```
<div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'>
    <label class='btn btn-default btn-sm active'>
        <input type='radio' name='course[]' value='" . $course->course_id . "' autocomplete='off'> No
    </label>
    <label class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>
        <input type='radio' name='course[]' value='" . $course->course_id . "' autocomplete='off'> Yes
    </label>
</div>
```

But I'm really struggling to work out how to differentiate between the different groups when the form is posted.

Ideally I have an array, and then loop through and post as appropriate, but each btn-group needs to have a different name, how can I do this?

Currently its only posting the last selected button.

Comment: so change the `name='course[]'` to something else for each group. `name='course1[]'`, `name='course2[]'` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You share the name across all radio buttons and give the same value for each course for both corresponding ones. That will not work. Do the following:

```
<div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons'>
    <label class='btn btn-default btn-sm active'>
        <input type='radio' name='course[$course->course_id]' value='no' autocomplete='off'> No
    </label>
    <label class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>
        <input type='radio' name='course[$course->course_id]' value='yes' autocomplete='off'> Yes
    </label>
</div>
```

Access it on the server via `$_POST["course"][$course->course_id]` and check if it's either `yes` or `no`

Comment: Yes, but as the course list is dynamic and grows over time, i need to loop through the results, i cant hard code each course. I need to `foreach(posted course selected){post to db}`

Comment: @frobak you could do a `foreach ($_POST["course"] as $courseId => $value)` and then check `if  ($value == "yes") { } else {}`

Answer (score 0):

For an easy solution you could easily make the names unique to the courses as well. That way only 1 course id can have a yes or no answer and you can get it via the course id's.

```
<label class='btn btn-default btn-sm'>
    <input type='radio' name='course".$course->course_id."[]' value='" . $course->course_id . "' autocomplete='off'> Yes
</label>
```

Comment: ok, but then how can I process these when I don't know how many there are, and they all have a different name. So I couldn't loop through all instances of 'course'?